# Do smooth manifolds admit smooth metric structures?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Say we have a smooth manifold $M$. Does there always exist a metric function $d : M \times M \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $d$ is smooth and gives rise to the same topology of the manifold $M$ ?

I am inclined to think that the answer is affirmative. One could argue that by [strong Whitney embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem) , $M$ could be embedded in the Euclidean space. Now the restriction of the ordinary metric on the Euclidean space to the manifold would satisfy the conditions. Am I right, or am I making some mistake ?
Thanks !

Comment: I think [this mathoverflow thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21295/smoothness-of-distance-function-in-riemannian-manifolds) probably answers your question.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Only if the OP wants it to come from a Riemannian metric. Otherwise their proof (as applied to the squared distance function) is correct.